# QMap Visual Studio error

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, qml

Hello I have project which i can compile in Qt Creator. Now I installed `Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate` and `Qt AddIn`. When I try Debug this project in `Visual Studio` I get error:
`Error 4 error C2661: 'QMap<int, Model*>::QMap' : no overloaded function takes 5 arguments  D:\projekt... 24 1 projekt`

definition of QMap:

```
QMap<int, Model*> modelItems =
    {
        {1, new Model("One")},
        {2, new Model("Two")},
        {3, new Model("Three")},
        {4, new Model("Four")},
        {5, new Model("Five")},
    };
```

And my next question:
* Is there possibility to compile version for Windows Phone if I use qml for GUI ?

Comment: First part of your question is duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420407/qmap-iteration-crash

Comment: And could you please post two different questions as different questions?

Comment: The first part of the question say that QMap cannot be initialized with initializer list, whereas 31420407 discusses a runtime crash.

Comment: Also, I am using initializer list syntax for QMap with VS 2013 and Qt 5.4.1 in real code with no issues, either compile or runtime. And the above code snippet compiles for me as well. What Qt version do you have?

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.5. I will update Visual Studio ASAP and try again.

Comment: After updated to Update 5 i get other error:
`Error 1 error C2797: 'Model::number': list initialization inside member initializer list or non-static data member initializer is not implemented .../project/model.h `